# Multiple cache bag for each tenant

Tags: caching, ehcache, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I am implementing second level cache in my project with hibernate + spring + terracotta and i want multiple cache bag for each tenant(organization). 
Like if i am logged in with 1st tenant and there is listing of department and saved in cache.
When i logged in with 2nd tenant and here is also the department listing but the listing is different from 1st tenant department, and i want this cache in different file.

Please anybody tell me the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance